# Use OCR Text reader to save the text

Tags: java, android, ocr, android-vision

I followed the OCR text reader guide on Codelabs (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#0).
Now, I would like to save, a single portion of the text that I am scanning.
I tried with reducing width, and height of the preview; but it doesn't work, the APK crashes (at least on the only device I have to test it).
I am completely new to Java, and Android development, but my Internship mentor said to do this; completely alone, with zero help (as no one in the company knows about development).

So, the app opens, it recognizes text. Now, I would like to to know if there is a way to take that text, and save it (XML or TXT file).
I tried to look in the code, and see if at some point, the text read is saved in a variable or something; but it looks like a live preview, done trough the Google's dependencies (or a similar process).

I am not sure, but this might be off topic, as it is similar to an open question, but I am giving details on what I have done so far, and what I have tried.

Thanks.

Comment: (code can be found on the codelabs link, they also have the entire zip file. If you don't trust the link just google it). I thought about putting the code here, but it is too long, and because I am new, I don't know which file are important.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but on the page I don't find anything about looping it, or using TextBlock#getValue(). Can you send the link? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The detected text is displayed in the `OcrGraphic.draw(Canvas)` method. There, it is returned as a `TextBlock`. You can call `textBlock.getComponents()` to get the lines and `textBlock.getComponents()` again to get each individual word (as a `Text` object).

Then you can convert it to a string and write the text to a file if you would like.